# Powershell script export formatting issues

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My code below works to run through group membership and pull the full path. I have some users who have exceeded the csv cell size limit and for these users I would like to split the long string into two. I have done that below and everything works as expected, except the format of the CSV. I will get the first string in the proper column but the second string jumps to the next row and writes to the second column in. I think it has something to do with a new line or an issue with commas but cannot get it figured out. Thoughts? Is there a quirk with SubStrings to add a new line to a CSV

```
$memberOf = $i.Properties.memberof
#This Array will hold Group Names to which the user belongs.
$UserGroupMembership = @()
Foreach($UserGroup in $memberOf){
    #Here we will add each group Name to UserGroupMembership array
    $UserGroupMembership += $UserGroup
}
#As the UserGroupMembership is array we need to join element with '; ' as the seperator
$Groups = $UserGroupMembership -join '; '
$GroupCount = $UserGroupMembership.length
#write-host $memberOf

$GroupMembership = "None"
$GroupOverflowVar = "None"
if($Groups.length -gt 32767){
    $GroupMembership = $Groups.SubString(0, 32759)
    $GroupOverflowVar = $Groups.SubString(32759)
}
else{
    $GroupMembership = $Groups
}
```

Comment: Why would you over complicate yourself with this when you can have 1 group per cell and that would give you an actual sortable / filterable data export?

Comment: Because each user has info and one column is all the groups they are in, if I broke the groups up I feel the CSV file would become unreadable. With this, I can filter a column in the CSV to see if someone is in a particular group. The users who have large strings for groups are sometimes apart of 300+ groups. 300 extra cells would be too difficult to run through

Comment: Think about it, suppose you have the export as 1 group per cell and you want to know if a user is part of group, you simply need to (on Excel) filter the user column by the user you're looking for and then filter by the membership column for the group name. If instead you lay down the membership horizontally you would need to check multiple columns trying to find where the group you are looking for is (not only this but your script will require an additional check to make sure you're not truncating the group name)

Comment: Lets say I went with that, then there would be enormous amounts of repetition no? My method works by having one user per row and then all groups in one column, in CSV I just filter the column by "contains." Where the method you suggest would repeat the user and their info the number of times their group count is, as your suggesting a group per row